# Gravar e recuperar informações em arquivos

Tags: c#, .net, arquivo, exceção, stream-de-arquivos

Como eu faço para gravar dados em um arquivo e depois recuperá-lo?

Tenho um sistema de matrículas. Inicio uma pasta no Windows e dentro dela vou gerando as matrículas de forma sequencial. Termino e vou para casa e no dia seguinte, vou gerar novo *set* de matrículas, mas devo começar da última e ir somando mais um: `matricula_atual + 1`. Preciso continuar gravando nele sem perder o que já existia.

Como eu gravo o arquivo em uma pasta?

Comment: Isto resolveu? Dá para aceitar alguma das respostas?

Answer (score 3):

**Testar se arquivo existe:**

```
if(File.Exists(@"C:\arquivo.txt"))
    // faça algo
```

**Realizar escrita de várias linhas em arquivo (sobreescreve conteúdo):**

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText (@"c:\arquivo.txt", "Matricula");
```

**Ler conteúdo do arquivo texto:**

```
public static string ObtenhaConteudoDeArquivoTexto(string pathArquivo)
{
     StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(pathArquivo);
     string text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
     streamReader.Close();
     return text;
}
```

**Inclui conteúdo para um arquivo físico:**

```
File.AppendAllText(@"c:\arquivo.txt", "NúmeroMatricula" + Environment.NewLine);
```

Primeiro, você utilizará o método de escrita em arquivo para realizar a primeira armazenagem de suas matrículas.

Depois, você deve utilizar o método para leitura do conteúdo do arquivo e preferencialmente, converter isto em dados concretos (porque tudo virá como string). Crie objetos, tipe corretamente os dados.

Depois, incremente via código os dados e utilize o método de inclusão de linha.

Em todas as situações, você deve analisar se irá realizar um *teste da existência do arquivo*.

Answer (score 3):

Resolvi responder porque apesar da outra resposta funcionar, ela tem uma forma equivocada de fazer a operação. Há 2 problemas.

Primeiro incentiva a existência de uma [condição de corrida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101) quando um arquivo que não existia passa existir entre a verificação e a sua tentativa de criação. Alguém pode dizer que é raro ocorrer isto. Pode em algumas situações, em outras não. Então é melhor ensinar as pessoas fazer do jeito correto. Infelizmente a documentação não ajuda e ensina do jeito errado.

E ainda há uma execução que fecha o arquivo de forma independente, o que não ocorrerá se houver uma exceção.

Então usando o mesmo exemplo da resposta, o correto seria algo assim:

```
try {
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"c:\arquivo.txt", "Matricula");
} catch (IOException ex) {
    WriteLine("deu erro"); //obviamente deve fazer outras coisas aqui
}
```

Esta é a forma segura (ou quase, continue lento) de executar esta operação. Não só pode haver o problema da condição de corrida, mas outros problemas podem ocorrer durante a execução do [`WriteAllText()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0#System_IO_File_WriteAllText_System_String_System_String_). Olhando a documentação deste método vemos que ele pode disparar várias exceções. É claro que você não precisa tratar todas individualmente e pode até deixar de tratar todas, mas provavelmente não terá a melhor forma resolver quando ocorrer um problema.

Uma coisa que é muito comum é o programador criar o código, testar em condições controladas e achar que tudo está certo. Mas é necessário testar tudo o que pode acontecer com ele. Deve se forçar a execução de todas as exceções possíveis, por exemplo, e ver o que acontece quando elas são disparadas. Se o programadores estiver satisfeito com tudo, ótimo. Se ele perceber que não pode acontecer o que está acontecendo nestas condições **excepcionais**, ele precisa tomar providências, precisa mudar o código para tratar isto. No caso de exceções é o uso do `try-catch` que permitirá um tratamento mais granular. Onde colocar ele e para quais exceções, depende de cada situação.

Então tenha em mente que o exemplo acima não trata bem também, porque diversas outras exceções comuns não foram tratadas.

Em alguns casos para cada exceção o código deve tomar uma ação diferente. Neste caso você precisaria ter um `catch` para cada exceção possível (conforme a documentação, programador tem que se acostumar ler documentação corretamente). Nenhum segredo.

Nos caso onde é possível tratar várias exceções com a mesma ação, até o C# 5 era ruim de tratar porque ou fazia vários `catch`s e replicava a ação, mesmo que seja a chamada de um método padrão, ou capturava uma exceção genérica e filtrava com um `if` dentro do `catch`:

```
catch (Exception ex) {                
    if (ex is IOException || 
        ex is UnauthorizedAccessException || 
        ex is NotSupportedException || 
        ex is SecurityException || 
        ex is DirectoryNotFoundException || 
        ex is PathTooLongException) {
        WriteLine("deu erro");
    }
    throw;
}
```

No C# 6 é possível filtrar a exceção conforme [resposta minha no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29390908/221800):

```
catch (Exception ex) when (ex is IOException || 
                           ex is UnauthorizedAccessException || 
                           ex is NotSupportedException || 
                           ex is SecurityException || 
                           ex is DirectoryNotFoundException || 
                           ex is PathTooLongException) {
    WriteLine("deu erro");
}
```

Deliberadamente deixei as outras duas exceções documentadas de fora já que elas são erros de programação e não de execução e deve quebrar a aplicação mesmo, ou seja, devem ser tratadas em outro local de forma mais genérica.

Para fazer a adição no arquivo texto deve-se observar a mesma situação, então as exceções possíveis no [`AppendAllText()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendalltext?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0#System_IO_File_AppendAllText_System_String_System_String_) devem ser tratadas adequadamente.

Tem outras maneiras de fazer isto e dependendo da situação pode ser preferível.

Assim como para ler os dados também existem várias maneiras. Uma delas:

```
using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(@"c:\arquivo.txt")) {
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8, true, BufferSize)) {
        while ((var line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null) {
            //faz algo com a linha
        }
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/WriteTextAll.cs).

Tem maneiras mais "prontas" para fazer isto mas note o importante uso do `using` para garantir o fechamento do arquivo mesmo que uma exceção ocorra.

É claro que se você quiser tratar melhor a exceção, vai substituir o `using` por um `try-catch`.

Veja também o [`ReadLines()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0#System_IO_File_ReadLines_System_String_) (o exemplo na documentação mostra o uso com `try-catch` mas lembre-se que é apenas um exemplo).

E obviamente é possível ler de uma vez só e evitar o `using` com o [`File.ReadAllText()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0#System_IO_File_ReadAllText_System_String_). É claro que se houver alguma falha nele, é necessário tratar também. O arquivo pode não existir na hora que abre ele. E acho que já deu para entender que se verificar se existe e depois tentar abrir, não garante nada. Para isto que existem exceções.